# How to Create a HTML animatation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

If you look at the [Google Docs landing page](https://www.google.co.uk/docs/about/), as you scroll down, you can see that there are animations such as this computer's screen is animated:

[image: HTML Animation example]

I would like to do something similar. There are other solutions such as an animated SVG, a GIF or a video however I would like to understand how this solution is done.

I'm aware I could use Javascript to create something like this, however surely there must be a library I haven't come across which would automate this process?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the css3 animation

Comment: Right click page -> inspect element and find out.

Comment: There are NUMEROUS libraries and techniques to do animation. But, understand that really there is just JavaScript and CSS at the core of any of those solutions. With CSS3 transitions, transforms and animations, much can be accomplished with CSS alone that use to require JavaScript.  You really need to be more specific as to what you really want to know.

Comment: @PeeHaa I already did, however there was not much.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular example you bring up - I believe they are using a handful of .png images inside of carefully sized divs which are being powered by pure CSS animations - I concluded this by just looking through the inspect element tool which comes with Google Chrome's developer tools.  To see for yourself, just right click on the page and select 'inspect element'.

[image]